# C# how to write Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

My file has certain data like::

> /Pages 2 0 R/Type /Catalog/AcroForm
>
> /Count 1 /Kids [3 0 R]/Type /Pages
>
> /Filter /FlateDecode/Length 84

What is the regular expression to get this output..

```
Pages Type Catalog AcroForm Count Kids Type Pages Filter FlateDecode Length
```

I want to fetch string after '/' & before 2nd '/' or space.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        string s = @"/Pages 2 0 R/Type /Catalog/AcroForm
/Count 1 /Kids [3 0 R]/Type /Pages
/Filter /FlateDecode/Length 84";

        var regex = new Regex(@"[\/]([^\s^\/]*)[\s]");
        foreach (Match item in regex.Matches(s))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Groups[1].Value);
        }

    }
}
```

Remark: Don't use regular expressions to parse PDF files.

Comment: Because the PDF specification is 8.6MB (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) and it is unlikely you will get it right with a regular expression. There are tools for this.

Answer (score 3):

```
\/[^\/\s]+
```

`\/` -- A slash (escaped)
`[^    ]` -- A character class not (`^`) containing...
`\/` -- ... slashes ...
`\s` -- ... or whitespace
`+` -- One or more of these

Comment: it doesnt work...
it gives error- Unrecognized escape sequence

Answer (score 1):

Here it is for c#:

```
@"/([^\s/]+)"
```

You can test it here just adding what is in between quotes:
http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a regex for this, I find that using string operations is more readable:

```
string[] lines = input.split(@"\");
foreach(string line in lines)
{
    if(line.contains(" "))
    {
         // Get everything before the space
    }
    else
    {
         // Get whole string
    }
}
```